# making a photo slide 1px per 20 milliseconds

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help making the transition duration, specifically, when the photo slide to the left, it slides 1px per 20 milliseconds.

The transition should happen when clicking on the photo itself, not the bars below.
While the sliding is in process, clicking the image will not have any effect.

When the second image takes the place of the first one, the first image will take place(circular fashion).

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #34495e;
}
.slidershow{
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.middle{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.navigation{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
}
.bar{
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  margin: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.bar:hover{
  background: #fff;
}

input[name="r"]{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slides{
  width: 500%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.slide{
  width: 20%;
  transition: 0.02s;
}
.slide img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#r1:checked ~ .s1{
  margin-left: 0;
}
#r2:checked ~ .s1{
  margin-left: -20%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>hw3</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="slidershow middle">

      <div class="slides">
        <input type="radio" name="r" id="r1" checked>
        <input type="radio" name="r" id="r2">

        <div class="slide s1">
          <img src="1.jpg" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="2.jpg" alt="image">
        </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="navigation">
        <label for="r1" class="bar"></label>
        <label for="r2" class="bar"></label>

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Yasser, I'm not sure what do you want exactly, do you want the right image to slide to the left, and when it covers the left one the left image should slide to the right, so they swap places at the end?

Comment: when opening the page, the first image will be visible you, clicking it will make slide to the left out of it's frame at 1px / 20milliseconds. when clicking the second image, the first one will appear in it's place restarting the slide show, sliding to the right and the first takes it's place, suddenly with no effect, or sliding to the left. Do it how ever you like, the most important thing i need is, 1-clicking the first will make it slide to the left 1px / 20milliseconds making the second image appear in it's place, 2-in the process of sliding clicking the image will have no effect @Firstdev